# How to get the language of my Wiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki, multilingual

I got a Wiki setup running different languages like so:

- `es.myWiki.org`
- `de.myWiki.org`
- `en.myWiki.org`

Now I need to get the different languages for a social buttons hook. It needs to differ depending on language.

I am using JS like this so far in my `customSkin.php`:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

if (userLang == "en-US") {
    userLang = "en_US";
} else if (userLang == "de-DE") {
    userLang = "de_DE";
} else if (userLang == "es-ES") {
    userLang = "es_ES";
};
```

I obviously have the problem if someone has a German browser, but views the page in English. How can I detect my Wiki language?

My setup uses one `localsettings.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the “site content language”. This is *not* the page language, and will normally be the same across all pages in your variant (`es` for `es.myWiki.org`, etc), regardless of the user's language settings. In other words, on `es.myWiki.org/aPage?uselang=en`, it will still be `es`.

### Frontend

```
var contentLang = mw.config.get( 'wgContentLanguage' );
```

### Backend

```
global $wgLanguageCode;
// do something with $wgLanguageCode
```

### API

Query `api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo` to get data on e.g. site content language (in `query.general.lang`). ([demo](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo))

### See also:

- [wgDefaultLanguageVariant](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDefaultLanguageVariant), for determining what script variety should be used for e.g. Chinese (simplified or traditional) or Serbian (latin or cyrillic)
- [Manual:Language](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Language), for more on page content language, site content language and user language.

Comment: I get "mw is not defined". Where should this go? Into `customPage.php`?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impresssion that you wanted to do this in the front end, as your code example was in JavaScript. The above code is Javascript. You can try it out in the developer's console in your browser, or add it to any JS running on your wiki (e.g. `MediaWiki:Commons.js`, if enabled).  Did you in fact want to do it in the backend? If yes, is it in a skin, or in an extension?

Comment: I have got a custom skin. I wanted to do it in the BG.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer, and remove the Javascript tag from your question, then

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the `window.location.href`:

```
var loc = window.location.host;
var userLang = loc.substr(0, loc.indexOf('.'));
```

This will give you `en, es, de`, depending on the subdomain the user is using.